# read xml from dataset

Tags: c#, xml, datareader

I posted a question on this topic but no luck, so here goes:

I have an asmx web service, with that web service I parse a given XML document using given XSD schema. I parse the XML doc in a way such that first I transform XML to string and then I put it into a DataSet. I'm parsing the data set and with that I pass data to database.

I have a little problem, I have this complex node:

```
<QuantityInIssueUnit uom="KO">288.000</QuantityInIssueUnit>
```

I have to extract "KO" and "288.000" values, using xsd I wrote this code:

```
if (!dr_art_line.Table.Columns.Contains("QuantityInIssueUnit") || dr_art_line["QuantityInIssueUnit"].ToString().Length <= 0)
{
    QuantityInIssueUnit.Value = 0;
    QuantityInIssueUnit.uom = "";
}
else
{
    QuantityInIssueUnit.Value = Convert.ToDecimal(dr_art_line["QuantityInIssueUnit"]);
    QuantityInIssueUnit.Value = QuantityInIssueUnit.Value.ToString().Length > 15 ? Convert.ToDecimal(QuantityInIssueUnit.Value.ToString().Substring(0, 14)) : QuantityInIssueUnit.Value;

    QuantityInIssueUnit.uom = Convert.ToString(dr_art_line["QuantityInIssueUnit uom"]);
}
```

But, it's not working, I assume that there is no node "QuantityInIssueUnit", it's always 0...

So is there a way to write this but using DataRow?

Answer (score 0):

So far I wrote this pice of code and it's working:

```
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(str)))
                            {
                                //UOM
                                reader.ReadToFollowing("QuantityInIssueUnit");
                                reader.MoveToFirstAttribute();
                                string value = reader.Value;
                                QuantityInIssueUnit_uom = value;  
                            }
```

I get QuantityInIssueUnit_uom = KO, that's what I wanted, now I just have to write a pice to  get 288.000, any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

And also this is the code for the value 288

```
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(str)))
                            {
                                reader.ReadToFollowing("QuantityInIssueUnit");

                                if (reader.Read())
                                {
                                    // I want to get all the TEXT contents from the this node
                                    QuantityInIssueUnit_value = reader.Value;

                                }

                            }
```

It's a little bit different but it works....